# Is there a way to add 2 days to a date string of characters in a text file?

Tags: powershell

I have a file where the 2nd date field needs to be set to 2 days after the first date field in a text file for every record. For example, a record contains the following string:

11/24/2019  **-----**

and I want to replace the **'-----'** dashes with 11/26/2019 so that it shows as

11/24/2019      **11/26/2019**

Has anyone done this using a PowerShell script?

Comment: take a look at what shows if you assign a datetime object to a $Var & then add a `.`  to trigger intellisense. the various `.Add*()` methods seem to fit what you want. [*grin*]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# Create sample input file
@'
11/24/2019 -----
01/01/2019 -----
'@ > sample.txt

# Process each line of the file
Get-Content sample.txt | ForEach-Object {
  '{0} {1}' -f ($dt = (-split $_)[0]), 
               ([datetime] $dt).AddDays(2).ToString('MM/dd/yyyy')
}
```

The above yields (2 lines):

```
11/24/2019 11/26/2019
01/01/2019 01/03/2019
```

Explanation:

- `$dt = (-split $_)[0]` uses the unary form of the [`-split` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_split) to split the input line at hand (`$_`) by whitespace, extracts the first (`[0]`) token, and assigns it to variable `$dt`
- `([datetime] $dt).AddDays(2)` casts the date string to a [.NET `System.DateTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime) instance and calls its `.AddDays()` method to add 2 days.

  - `.ToString('MM/dd/yyyy')` formats the resulting date the same way as the input date string.
- `'{0} {1}' -f ...` uses the [format operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators#format-operator--f) to form a single output string from the two operands.